Recursive formula for the starting player to win. What am I getting wrong?

Two players take turns removing a ball from a jar that initially contains m white and n  black balls. The first player to remove a white ball wins. Develop a recursive formula that allows the convenient computation of the probability that the starting player wins.

The answer is $P(m, n) = \dfrac{m}{m + n} +  \dfrac{n}{m + n}(1 - P(m, n -1))$
I'm aware that this question has been asked a couple of times on this site. However, I clearly have yet to understand the solution even after reading the answers on those threads. In particular, I don't understand why my solution isn't the same: Let $P(m, n)$ be the probability that the starting player wins when the jar has $m$ white balls and $n$ black balls. Given any valid inputs of $m, n$, the starting player could win immediately or win in subsequent rounds. The latter requires that both the starting player and the other player lose this round for the next round to begin (i.e. both pick the black balls). Thus:
$$P(m, n) = 
\begin{cases} 
\dfrac{m}{m + 1} & \text{if } n = 1, \\
1 & \text{if } n = 0, \\
\dfrac{m}{m + n} + \dfrac{n}{m + n}\cdot\dfrac{n - 1}{m + n - 1}\cdot P(m, n -2) & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$
I hope someone could explain what I am getting wrong. Thank you!

If $m=0$, it's a draw. If $m>0$, the first player always wins, by just looking into the jar and picking out a white ball. Easy!

@GerryMyerson You're right! It should have been specified that the draws are random. :P

You are not getting anything wrong. Both solutions are correct. From the correct solution, you can get
$$P(m,n-1)=1-\frac{n-1}{m+n-1}P(m,n-2)$$
which gives your answer when you plug it back (except when $n=1$ and in that case as well, the two formulas give the same result).
The other formula simply goes as: $m/(m+n)$ probability to win on the first turn, else $n/(m+n)$ times the probability that the other person does not win, which is $1-P(m,n-1)$.
Hope this helps. :)

Thank you! I think I've finally understood both my solution and the original solution now!

Both the formulae are correct, as has been pointed out in another answer, but the first formula, which you have quoted from some source, is better, because the two salient terms are $P(m,n)$ and $P(m,n-1)$ which is the simplest (one step) recursive formula.
Yours is in terms of $P(m,n)$ and $P(m,n-2)$
You could as well derive a recursion in terms of $P(m,n)$ and $P(m,n-4)$ but what would be the point ?

Thank you! I think I've finally understood both my solution and the original solution now!

You're welcome !
